# Firebase Datasnapshot Observable not updating immediately after login via redirect

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, angular-cli

friends.

So, I'm not grokking this RxJS thing as it pertains to Angular.  I've got a Promise working (user authentication event),
but my attempt to get data asynchronously from Firebase ain't going quite as well.

This code works, for the most part, except in one case: when the user logs in (via redirect).  In that case, we see the 
user-authentication event occur, then (presumably) a change-detection cycle runs that results in the UI being updated to 
show the currently-logged-in user, then (presumably) a databasse event comes in from Firebase (which we see logged in the
console), but there's not another change-detection cycle (and I assume there should be), so the UI doesn't update with the 
new info from the d/b.  If I wait 10-15 seconds (roughly; I haven't actually timed it), OR if I type something in the UI's 
text field, THEN the UI updates with the data snapshot.

I hook up the Observable to a Firebase event via `Observable.fromEventPattern()`.

This thing works like a champ if you're already logged in and you open 
or refresh the page.  It just doesn't work  if you're trying to log in.  It probably doesn't help that I don't fully
understand what's going on in the redirect, either.

So... what have I done wrong?  (I'm sure I've done a number of things wrong, actually.)

I have a toy application at https://github.com/JohnL4/FirebaseRxPlay/releases/tag/problem-reproduction  that reproduces my problem.

Comment: Why the "close" votes?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem in my project. I feel like it's related to zone.js and how angular detect if there are changes, because you have to trigger some action that causes a view update in order to see your the changes. 
I decided to run all firebase's callbacks within NgZone like this

```
tagsRef.on('value', snapshot => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        const tags = Object.keys(snapshot.val() || {});
        observer.next(tags);
    });
});
```

I did the same thing for the auth callback too

```
getAuthRedirectResult$(): Observable<firebase.auth.UserCredential> {
    return new Observable<firebase.auth.UserCredential>(observer => {
      this.firebaseService.auth.getRedirectResult()
        .then((result: firebase.auth.UserCredential) => {
           if (result.user) {
             this.zone.run(() => {
               observer.next(result);
             });
           }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
          observer.error(error);
         });
    });
});
```

This solved the problem for me.

The only thing that I'm not sure about is why this problem only happens after a auth's redirect.

EDIT #1:

I looked into this a bit more, and apparently after a redirect firebase auth callbacks run in `<root>` zone, instead of `angular` zone. So that explains why change detection does not get triggered.

Edit #2:
The below commit in angularfire2 repo says that firebase could add websocket listener before angular Zone exists. So I think it is the reason why I'm seeing the auth callbacks run in `<root>` zone instead of `angular` zone.

> Since Firebase is adding WebSocket listeners before the Angular Zone exists,
>   all callbacks when data is received are being executed outside of Angular's
>   zone and are not triggering change detection

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/648/commits/8b2c7a400418a68b6f25654067ce6cf918ceb681